# Convert C# DateTime to SQL Date and insert with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to use the Date type on SQL because I only need the YYYY-MM-DD format, the problem is that I can't parse the DateTime into the SQL Date, I leave the code of SQL and C#

--SQL

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR(
    DateID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY (DateID),
    Day Date
);

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateDate
@Day, @haserror bit out
AS
begin try
    set @haserror = 0
    insert into CALENDAR(Day)
    values
    (@Day)
end try
begin catch
    set @haserror = 1;
end catch
```

--C#

```
public bool CreateDayCalendar(DateTime date)
{
    var result = false;
    try
    {
        if (_client.Open())
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = _client.Connection,
                CommandText = "CreateDate",
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            var par1 = new SqlParameter("@Day", SqlDbType.Date)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = **How do I put the DateTime here**
            };

            var par2 = new SqlParameter("@haserror", SqlDbType.Bit)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };

            command.Parameters.Add(par1);
            command.Parameters.Add(par2);

            result = !Convert.ToBoolean(command.Parameters["@haserror"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        _client.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I don't know if the problem is how to parse the DateTime to Date, or do I have to change the property Day inside Calendar to another type?}

--EDIT

I forgot a line of code

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There was no mistake while parsing

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try `Value = date.Date` ?

Comment: You just put `date` there. It'll figure it out. The `YYYY-MM-DD` format is a separate concern from how things are stored. You can display a `DateTime` however you want.

Comment: Odd that you asked a question without just trying putting the date there?

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff but none worked lol, let me try with what you are suggesting

Comment: Its normal to show what you tried when you ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `date` or `date.Date`:

```
var par1 = new SqlParameter("@Day", SqlDbType.Date)
{
     Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
     Value = date.Date
};
```

Comment: Yep. ADO.Net will handle the conversion for you. A C# datetime object can be assigned directly to an ADO.Net SqlParameter.Value property that will map to a Sql Server date value.